# Converting coef function of R in Python

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have R script which calculates the Intercept according to the code mentioned below

```
library(zoo)
data = matrix(rexp(200), 10)
X <- data[,3]
Y <- data[,4]
input <- cbind(X,Y)
betas <- rollapply(input,width=2,FUN=function(z) coef(lm(Y~X,data = as.data.frame(z))),by.column=FALSE,align="right")
```

I was looking for the python function which helps me in achieving that! What options I have here?

Comment: Not completely sure what you exactly want. If you want to use Linear Regression in Python you could use the sklearn library. sklearn objects have coef attributes in a similar way as in R.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. You could use the LinearRegression function from the scikit-learn library:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1, 5], [5, 2], [7, 2], [34, 3]])
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 6
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
reg.coef_
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit regression you can use scikitlearn or statmodels. Scikitlearn is more user friendly if you know OOP.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# create a random sample
X_sample = np.random.normal(10, 5, 10)
# create a model simulation
y_sample = 3 + 4*X_sample + np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
# Scikitlearn expect X values as array of array
X = np.expand_dims(X_sample, axis=1)

# fit a model
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y_sample)
# Alternative fit
# lrm = LinearRegression()
# reg = lrm.fit(X, y_sample)

# print r-square, intercept value and coefficients
print(reg.score(X, y_sample))
print(reg.intercept_)
print(reg.coef_)
```

By the way it is not a pandas problem. You can have a look on Scikit-learn api how to use pandas dataframe for splinting, and training model.